# appending to array A with array B (being a reference to array A??)

Tags: php, arrays, append

I have two variables, which are both arrays:

```
$var1=array();

$var1['something']['secondary_something'][1]="foo";
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][2]="foo";
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][3]="foo";
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][4]="foo";
```

Now I have a function, that takes an array for input:

```
function something($input=array()){

print_r($input);//print the array out

}//end of function
```

But I need `$input` to be like a reference to `$var1`, so when I call the function, appending to variable 2 (`$input`) like this:

```
$myInputVar=array();
$myInputVar['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo";
$myInputVar['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo";
//Notice how I append to the var above, not giving a key name in the third dimension of the array.
something($myInputVar);
```

Now that would simply print:

```
Array ( [something] => Array ( [secondary_something] => Array ( [0] => foo [1] => foo ) ) )
```

But I need the second var (`$input`, from the function) to be a reference of the first var (`$var1`).

So, the end result should be:

```
Array ( [something] => Array ( [secondary_something] => Array ( [5] => foo [6] => foo ) ) )
```

Some guys have told me to use the `=&` (which makes one var a reference to another), but I just can't seem to get my head around how I would do it with `=&` in this case.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so, could you please shine some light on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am struggling to understand what you are trying to achieve.
Why would you print the array out?
You always need a value and an array if you want to push something into the array.
You can do this with

```
function something(&$array, $val) { // take the assigned $array as reference
  $array[] = $val;
}
```

Then calling with

```
$test = array();
something($test, 'foo');
print_r($test); // => array ( 'test' )
```

I hope this helps

---

**EDIT**

```
function something(&$array, $array_new) {
   $array = array_merge($array, $array_new); // to combine/merge both arrays
   // please keep in mind that $array is technically $var, because it references to this variable
}

$var1=array();

$var1['something']['secondary_something'][1]="foo";
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][2]="foo";
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][3]="foo";
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][4]="foo";

$myInputVar=array();
$myInputVar['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo";
$myInputVar['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo";

something($var, $myInputVar);
```

Comment: Yeah, it was pretty hard to explain too. But I think you've misunderstood (sorry). The `print_r` is just there as an example. I'm trying to use `$var1` to append to `$var2`...so if I did `$var2[]="someting"` it would append that to `$var1` instead. make more sense now? Again, sorry for the weird explanation...

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function receive a reference to the array. Like so:

```
function something(&$arr) {
    $arr['something']['secondary_something'][]="something1";
    $arr['something']['secondary_something'][]="something2";
}
```

Now you can do something like the following:

```
$var1 = array();
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][1]="foo";
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][2]="bar";
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][3]="foobar";
$var1['something']['secondary_something'][4]="barfoo";
something($var1); //this should now append the items to $var1.
print_r($var1); //check to see if calling 'something' really did add the items.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$var1 = array();
$var2 = array();

assign($var1, $var2, 'foo'); // add an item in both $var1 & $var2
assign($var1, $var2, 'bar'); // append another item it both $var1 & $var2
assign($var1, $var2, 'buz', 5); // add an item in both $var1 & $var2 at index 5

echo print_r($var1, TRUE) . print_r($var2, TRUE);

function assign(&$var1, &$var2, $value, $index=NULL) {
    if (is_int($index)) {
        $var1['something']['secondary_something'][$index] = $var2['something']['secondary_something'][$index] = $value;
    } else {
        $var1['something']['secondary_something'][] = $var2['something']['secondary_something'][] = $value;
    }
}
```

which will output:

```
Array ( [something] => Array ( [secondary_something] => Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar [5] => buz ) ) ) Array ( [something] => Array ( [secondary_something] => Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar [5] => buz ) ) )
```